# Laravel Raw Expressions

Tags: php, sql, laravel

How do I write a Laravel raw expression that produces this results, I have year, gender and date of birth in my table and my main intention is to group by year as I group ages within ranges from 6-12, 13-17, 18-29... and also get gender count per age range. My table looks like this.

```
+------+--------+------------+
| year | gender | date_of_b  |
+------+--------+------------+
| 2016 | male   | 2004-05-01 |
| 2016 | male   | 1990-02-09 |
| 2016 | male   | 1960-04-14 |
| 2017 | female | 1975-03-08 |
| 2017 | male   | 1994-07-19 |
| 2017 | female | 2005-03-15 |
| 2018 | male   | 2010-05-30 |
| 2018 | female | 2000-04-11 |
| 2019 | male   | 1988-06-15 |
| 2019 | female | 1980-08-10 |
| 2019 | male   | 1990-03-18 |
+------+--------+------------+
```

This is the result I want

```
{ 
   2016: {
     '6-12': {
          male: 0, 
          female: 1 
      },
      '13-17': {
          male: 2, 
          female: 4 
      }
   },
   2017: {
     '6-12': {
          male: 10, 
          female: 12 
      },
      '13-17': {
          male: 21, 
          female: 24 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Laravel raw expression is just sql syntax. So this question is not Laravel specific. Beside that, `this result` that you want to produce is not only about query, but also including JSON formatting. So it will be easier for us to help you if you provide more information.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far in your controller to get the desired output?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via collection :

```php
User::get()->groupBy('year')->map(function($users){
    return $users->groupBy('range')->map(function($users){
        return $users->count();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DB::table('users')->groupBy('year')->get();
```

you can try this. And if this is not work show some related code.